# sed syntax to remove trailing space and colon

Tags: sed

I have a csv file from which I want to remove all instances of " output:" (the word output with a leading space and followed by a colon)

I tried

```
sed 's/\ output:\>//g' file.csv
```

to no avail.

However if I just try

```
sed 's/\output\>//g' file.csv
```

It works for the "output" only piece.

What would be the correct syntax to remove everything?

INPUT DESIRED
 output: whateverhost.domain.com, BBXXX,2016-05-13 18:27

OUTPUT DESIRED
whateverhost.domain.com, BBXXX,2016-05-13 18:27

Comment: You don't need to escape the space. The problem is that you don't well understand what the `\>` boundary is and in what situations it matches or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `sed 's/ output:.*//g'`.

There's no need for a leading `\`.

Comment: That kinda worked but removed the entire line containing the string, not just the string itself.